# Css text and image in the same line

Tags: html, css

I need to align pic-text-pic in a row.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #element1 {background: url('url1'); margin-right: 10px}
    #element2 {margin-right: 10px}
    #element2 {background: url('url2')}
</style>

<div id="element1">
    element 1 markup
</div>
<div id="element2">
    element 2 markup
</div>
<div id="element3">
    element 2 markup
</div>
```

I tried playing with it, just cant make it happend.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could add `display:inline-block` to the `<div>` styles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to research the various display properties of CSS and how these create layout in the browser. DIVs are by default "block level elements" which means they're each going to break onto a new line.

For your example, you'll want to look into the "inline" or "inline-block" display properties, which will get your elements to line up next to each other (as long as there is enough space in the parent container). So, try this:

```
#element1,
#element2,
#element3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The inline-block makes the pic disapear, it works with test for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<span>` tags instead of `<div>`s.

Comment: You shouldn't change the structure for presentational purposes. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block`:

```
#element1,
#element2,
#element3 {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: when i do that, the img disapears

Comment: You need to specify a size for the div, if you're using a background. Specify `width` and `height` properties for `#element1`.

Answer (score -1):

use `<span>` and not `<div>`